# Point-set topology and set theory

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

In the standard *second-order, but single-sorted* setting of [point-set topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_topology) one has a base set $X$ and the property of being *open* on its powerset $P$ obeying the usual axioms. Proofs in point-set topology rely on these axioms and on the fact that $P$ is the powerset of $X$, such that set theory can be applied.

> Which subset of the ZFC axioms is effectively necessary in this standard setting to be able to prove the theorems of point-set topology?

There is also a *first-order, but two-sorted* setting – unaware of subsets – with an extra relation (call it $\in$) in which analogues of the set theoretic axioms must be explicitly stated.

> Which subset of the ZFC axioms (relating the two sorts) has to be stated in this two-sorted setting to be able to prove the theorems of point-set topology?

Finally there is – assumably – a genuinely *first-order single-sorted* theory (knowing only the subsets, not the base set $X$) with one or more extra relations (call one of them $\subseteq$).

> Which extra relations have to be assumed and which subset of the ZFC axioms (relating these relations) have to be stated in this one-sorted setting to be able to prove the theorems of point-set topology?

Comment: I expect this to depend a lot of _which_ theorems you want to be able to prove. In a first-order setting where you can only speak of points and sets of points, it's not clear that one can even speak about, say, compactness, so you'd have to restrict yourself to a subset of point-set topology anyway.

Comment: Perhaps [pointless topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointless_topology) is close to what you're imagining as a single-sorted theory?

Comment: @Henning: Thanks for the hint (about *which* theorems to be able to prove). But don't you suggest that I have to *expand* my view on point-set topology (instead of restricting it) - to higher orders?

Comment: I'm not sure I can give you any general advice. It all depends on what you're aiming to do. It's certainly possible to write down some first-order axioms for a topological space, and reason formally about those, just like it is possible to study, say, the group axioms in algebra. But many interesting theorems in group theory cannot be formulated in the language of the group axioms, because they are about the relation between _different_ groups -- and usually the response to that is not to look to higher order formulations but just to use set theory whenever that's more convenient.

Comment: (cont.d) Another point is that the boundaries of "point-set topology" are not really well defined. Historically all of set theory -- including notions such as cardinality -- used to be considered to be a specialty within point-set topology. (Indeed, when I studied math, the mandatory set theory in the undergraduate curriculum was in a course entitled "general topology"). So if you broaden your scope enough it's likely that you end up doing set theory _anyway_. And I'm not sure there is any clear place to draw the line that is objectively better than other places you could choose to draw it.

Comment: @Hans: The question seems interesting, but I think you will have to be more explicit about what you mean by ‘theorems of point-set topology’ in order to get useful answers.

Comment: As Henning said, this is really about how you limit your topology. If you want it to be limited, you'd have to take an infinite chunk, probably close to the entire ZFC. Either way you would want to have extensionality, power set, union, infinity, foundation, choice. Should you insist on minimality perhaps there are a few pieces of replacement you can toss away. I doubt there can be a nice description of these without some further limitations in the question.